# Determining whether a file denotes an executable process

Tags: java, file, process

How can I determine whether a path is executable in the sense of launching a *Process* in Java? In other words:

```
new java.io.File("ls")     .canExecute();  // false (!)
new java.io.File("/bin/ls").canExecute();  // true
```

How can I work around the failure of the first line to detect that "ls" can be safely started as a process (without having to figure out its absolute location)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if path is simple try to search in PATH

Comment: So `java.lang.System.getenv.get("PATH")`? Is that identical to the way `Runtime.exec` will try to resolve the simple path? Is that cross-platform?

Comment: Yes. This is what you want. And it is not cross platform. On different platform you get string with different separator.  Separator is `File.pathSeparator`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching in `PATH` or using `File.canExecute()`, you could start `Process` and catch the exceptions (haven't tested though)

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("ls").start();
```